# Dynamic FTPSensor in Apache Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I want to implement a dynamic FTPSensor of a kind. Using the contributed FTP sensor I managed to make it work in this way:

```
ftp_sensor = FTPSensor(
        task_id="detect-file-on-ftp",        
        path="./data/test.txt",
        ftp_conn_id="ftp_default",
        poke_interval=5,
        dag=dag,
    )
```

and it works just fine. But I need to pass dynamic path and ftp_conn_id params. I.e. I generate a bunch of new connections in a previous task and in the ftp_sensor task I want to check for each of the new connections that I previously generated if there's a file present on the FTP.

So I thought first to grab the connections' ids from XCom.
I send them from the previous task in XCom but it seems I cannot access XCom outside of tasks.
E.g. I was aiming at something like:

```
active_ftp_connections = context['ti'].xcom_pull(key='active_ftps')
for conn in active_ftp_connections:
  ftp_sensor = FTPSensor(
        task_id="detect-file-on-ftp",        
        path=conn['path'],
        ftp_conn_id=conn['connection'],
        poke_interval=5,
        dag=dag,
    )
```

but this doesn't seem to be a possible solution.

Then I just wasted a good amount of time trying to create my custom FTPSensor to which to pass dynamically the data I need but right now I reached to the conclusion that I need a hybrid between a sensor and operator, because I need to keep the poke functionality for instance but also have the execute functionality.
I guess one option is to write a custom operator that implements poke from the sensor base class but am probably too tired to try to do it now.

Do you have an idea how to achieve what I am aiming at? I can't seem to find any materials on the topic on the internet - maybe it's just me.
Let me know if the question is not clear so I can provide more details.

**Update**

I now reached to this as possibility

```
def get_active_ftps(**context):
    active_ftp_connestions = context['ti'].xcom_pull(key='active_ftps')
    return active_ftp_connestions

for ftp in get_active_ftps():
    ftp_sensor = FTPSensor(
            task_id="detect-file-on-ftp",        
            path="./"+ ftp['folder'] +"/test.txt",
            ftp_conn_id=ftp['conn_id'],
            poke_interval=5,
            dag=dag,
        )
```

but it throws an error: `Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/copy_file_from_ftp.py] 'ti'`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it like this:

```
active_ftp_folder = Variable.get('active_ftp_folder')
active_ftp_conn_id = Variable.get('active_ftp_conn_id')
ftp_sensor = FTPSensor(
        task_id="detect-file-on-ftp",        
        path="./"+ active_ftp_folder +"/test.txt",
        ftp_conn_id=active_ftp_conn_id,
        poke_interval=5,
        dag=dag,
    )
```

And will just have the dag run one ftp account at a time since I realized that there shouldn't be cycles in a direct acyclic graphs ... apparently.